# Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for class in my project

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0

I am getting below error on initializing the `NavigationDrawerRecyclerViewAdapter`.

Now class `com.mypackage.app.NavigationDrawerRecyclerViewAdapter` exists and it is public and its constructor is public as well.

```
1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416fed58)
05-18 10:46:20.573 3669-3669/com.mypackage.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.mypackage.app, PID: 3669
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mypackage.app.NavigationDrawerRecyclerViewAdapter                                                                       at com.mypackage.app.FragmentDrawer.onCreateView(FragmentDrawer.java:68)
```

clean and rebuild project doesn't work. Any suggestions around what could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE too?

Comment: Is the package correct?

Comment: @PedroOliveira : Yes I tried restarting the IDE too


I am android studio 2.0 BTW

Comment: @Aurasphere : Yes the package is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I had multidex enabled and that was causing the problem.
I was using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' in my build.gradle while I needed only com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0.

Changing the above , I was able to run my application without enabling multidex which was causing class not found error.

This helped: [App not launching with multidexEnabled true in android studio - Famous 65k reference method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474555/app-not-launching-with-multidexenabled-true-in-android-studio-famous-65k-refer)

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Order and Export Tab.
Make sure that "Android Private Libraries" is checked for Export.
If libraries are already adde from the libs/ folder, remove them as they are automatically added in the "Android Private Libraries" section.

Comment: I am using android studio 2.0 as IDE , I am not able to find the exact path there

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError indicates that class was present during the time of compilation but not available when you run your application, sometimes error on static initializer block can also result in NoClassDefFoundError or context of this class not accessible.
So, make sure this class refers same class memory.